# How to execute route even if file is not send

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, multer

I have this atm:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest:'./public/upload'});
var session = require('express-session');
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
var crypto = require('crypto');


var upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({

    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './public/upload');
    },

    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      var ext = require('path').extname(file.originalname);
      ext = ext.length > 1 ? ext : "." + require('mime').extension(file.mimetype);
      require('crypto').pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
        cb(null, (err ? undefined : raw.toString('hex')) + ext);
      });
    }
  })
});



router.post('/registo',upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
```

as you guys can see i send the file in route.post, it works fine when the user send it, but if not i get a error, a internal server error(500) how can i execute the post without the file if the user didn't send anything?

Comment: If user didn't send any thing then you can check that if file then further processing otherwise response no file selected

Answer (score 0):

You can check that on client side and send (or not) proper (i.e. another) POST there.

On server side you can try to handle this situation:

```
router.post('/registo',upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    if(req.file.size === 0){
    ...
    }
...
}
```